# How to count the remaining uppercase letter T for the letter occurrences counter?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I need some guidance from the code I have here, which counts the alphabet letter occurrences from a sentence.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int wordCount = 0;
    String word = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the bank of the river";
    for (char letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if (word.charAt(i) == letter) {
                wordCount++;
            }
        }
        if (wordCount > 0) {
            System.out.print(letter + "=" + wordCount + ", ");
            wordCount = 0;
        }
    }
}
 

Output:
a=3, b=2, c=1, d=1, e=7, f=2, g=1, h=4, i=2, j=1, k=2, l=1, m=1, n=3, o=5, p=1, q=1, r=5, s=1, t=3, u=2, v=2, w=1, x=1, y=1, z=1,
```

My issue here is that my program doesn't seem to count the uppercase letter T at the start of my sentence; thus, the result of the occurrences of letter t lacks one more (since my expected output for the occurrences of t is 4, but it resulted in only 3)(This code is a little bit simple, but I'm a bit baffled in terms of utilizing loops and arrays.

Should I add another for loop in creating the alphabet letters but this time in an uppercase form and put them in an array?

Your responses and guides would really help me on this code that I am constructing.

Thank you very much, everyone!!!

Comment: why would it count `T`? look at your loop `for (char letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++) {... }`

Comment: @Eugene , yes I am aware of that since this loop focuses on lowercase.

Comment: change your loop to iterate on the indexes instead, isn't that easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, a `T` is not a `t`. Us humans tend to interpret them as (loosely) the same, but to a machine, they aren't.

You have three options here:

1. You could convert the whole string to lowercase, so `T` becomes `t` prior to processing the string. You could use `String::toLowerCase` for that.
2. You could also convert each character to lowercase using `Character::toLowerCase`. This will delegate the conversion to the `Character` class, which contains many methods to act upon a character.

   ```java
   if (Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(i)) == letter) {
       wordCount++;
   }
   ```
3. Another option is to do some arithmetic to convert the uppercase characters to lowercase.

   ```java
   char c = word.charAt(i);
   if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
       c += 32;
   }

   if (c == letter) {
       wordCount++;
   }
   ```

   This works because the difference between 'A' and 'a' is 32.

---

Note that your code is a little inefficient regarding time-complexity. You have a loop within a loop, so you're iterating 26 times over the whole string.

Another fairly well-known approach is to create an array of 26 positions, one for each letter. For each letter, you increment the value of the array index corresponding to the letter:

```java
// Let's agree that position 0 is for the 'a' and position 25 for the 'z'
int[] frequencies = new int[26];
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    char c = word.charAt(i);
    // <<Convert your character to lowercase here>>
    // Also check if your character is a Latin letter

    int position = c - 'a'; // Now 'a' => 0 and 'z' => 25
    frequencies[position]++;
}
```

Now, the only thing you need to do is loop over the `frequencies` array and print the quantities.

Comment: This is a very detailed response (especially that you progressively add more possible options for the implementation). This would indeed help me a lot in doing tweaks with my code structure! Much love and respect to you and thank you very much for your response and guidance!!!